Audio device keeps duplicating
I am running windows 11 version 23h2, on a victus gaming laptop with a built in rtx 2050(although I doubt that matters).
I am having an issue with my monitor(Sceptre M24) which is connected to my laptop via hdmi constantly duplicating its audio device, I have no clue whats causing it and after a couple hours my computer begins to slow down and it starts to eat up at all my memory causing intense issues with just doing anything.
https://imgur.com/a/VG942qh

Your image is inaccessible. Use the upload image function of the editor.

The issue may be coming from the video card driver. Make sure the driver is up to date first of all, and see if the issue goes away. You may also be able to disable audio in the Nvidia settings tool.
You might also try using a DisplayPort on the monitor to HDMI on the PC cable. DisplayPort does carry audio, but it might detect differently and prevent the issue. You could also try and find a DP adapter that is cheap enough that it doesn't bring the audio over.
